# Blazor redirect back to local url from external url

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I have a Blazor App where the user should do a login on an external login page (within intranet) and after login i want to redirect back to the apps main page (dashboard).
So what i want basically is the user opens the app and clicks the login button, then the app routes to the external login page, the user enters his username and password, after the user has logged in, the dashboard(home) from my app gets loaded and shown.

So i have a login button and when the user clicks it, he will be routed to "login.razor".
In "login.razor" i have the following code:

```
@page "/login"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        string homeUrl = "/";

        //First attempt:
        // This doesn't work
        //NavManager.NavigateTo($"http://external.login.page?redirectUrl={homeUrl}", forceLoad: true);

        // Second attempt: (doesn't work either)
        // Navigate to external login
        NavManager.NavigateTo($"http://external.login.page", forceLoad: true);

        // Navigate to Home of blazor app (this is suppose to be executed after the user has submitted the above login form)
        NavManager.NavigateTo($"{homeUrl}", forceLoad: true);
    }
}
```

The first attempt is not working as the server response is an error.
Second attempt doesn't work as the app routes almost instantly to "home" after the login page has been loaded.

Does someone has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Your concept of external login is not correct, when you navigate to external login, the external login should return the user to your blazor site. You don't have to call the `homeUrl` right after the external login, it will never work that way hence you are seeing the `homeUrl` straight away the user goes to login page.

Comment: After the external login, the server automatically redirects to its own home... but i don't want to display it's home. The login does not return the user. After login i can fetch the userinfo manually. All i want is just let the user enter the login information on the external login form. After that i would fetch the userdata manually from the server. Based on this response, i can determine what user it is and whether the login was succesful. The only problem is that the login redirects to the servers home and not to the home of my blazor page.

Comment: Have you got the answer to this one after two years?
for me it works only the first time and I think it is a caching issue

Answer (score 3):

I get your point it's something like Azure Active Directory or login with any external provider, basically the redirection process to the dashboard or the page you want should happen on the level of the login page not from your app, I mean the login page in the other app should receive a parameter called for example *redirect_uri* so the the code will look like this

```
// Navigate to external login
NavManager.NavigateTo($"http://external.login.page?redirect_url={home_uri}", forceLoad: true);
```

And on the level of the login application, if the login attempt goes well then get the value of that parameter and redirect the user to it.

Comment: That was the way i was thinking too, but i get a 405 error.

Comment: 405? Cloud you explain when you are getting this error? When submitting the login form?

Comment: Yes, when i submit the login form.

Comment: So in this case, this could be because of the verb, make sure to specify the type of action like decorate the Login action with [HttpPost]

Comment: Where am i suppose to decorate it? Could you edit your example above so i know what you mean?

Comment: The code I have written above is for the client, I mean the decoration should be in the login app in the action of submitting the form